# Passing list to NestWhileList

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to implement the secant root finding method [image: Secant Method]

using `NestWhileList` as follows:

```
NestWhileList[{#2, #2 - f[#2] (#2 - #1)/(f[#2] - f[#1])} &, {x0,x1}, 
               eps < Abs@@Differences[#] &, 1]
```

Where `{x0, x1}` is a list of numbers, and `f[x]` is a polynomial.This does not work ("Slot number 2 cannot be filled"). This is somewhat confusing as the documentation for `NestWhileList` says it

> [NestWhileList] generates a list of the results of *applying* f repeatedly...

I take this to mean that `Apply` is being used. If I use apply myself:

```
{#2, #2 - f[#2] (#2 - #1)/(f[#2] - f[#1])} & @@ {x0, x1}
```

It produces no error. The only way I can get the code to work is this hideous mess using `Part`:

```
NestWhileList[{#[[2]], #[[2]] - f[#[[2]]] (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/(f[#[[2]]] - f[#
             [[1]]])}&, {x0,x1},eps < Abs@@Differences[#] &, 1]
```

So my question is two-fold, 1) why does `Apply` by itself work differently than when `NestWhileList` applies the function, and, 2) is there a way for me to have cleaner code while still using slots (instead of writing a `Function`)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Applying" might be a bit misguiding. (since `NestWhileList` only passes one argument to the function, there's no reason to assume that it needs to `Apply` the function.

A simple fix that doesn't involve `Part` is to simply wrap your function in [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
NestWhileList[Apply[{#2, #2 - f[#2] (#2 - #1)/(f[#2] - f[#1])} &], {x0,x1}, 
           eps < Abs@@Differences[#] &, 1]
```

This is the operator form, which basically does the following:

```
Apply[f][{x,y,...}] --> Apply[f,{x,y,...}] --> f[x,y,...]
```